# how to take a single value in column depends on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server and I have table like this:

| id | size | reign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | large | Riyadh |
| 1 | small | Riyadh |
| 2 | large | Makkah |
| 2 | medium | Makkah |
| 2 | small | Jeddah |
| 3 | medium | Dammam |

I want a query to take only one size for each regain and id.
For example in id "1", I want to remove the second value ("small")
Notice: I can't alter or make changes in the table.

The result should be like this:

| id | size | reign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | large | Riyadh |
| 2 | large | Makkah |
| 2 | small | Jeddah |
| 3 | medium | Dammam |

Comment: What is the logic regarding which size is retained?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to prioritize large, medium, and small, in this order, we can try using `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, reign
                                 ORDER BY CASE size WHEN 'large'  THEN 1
                                                    WHEN 'medium' THEN 2
                                                    WHEN 'small'  THEN 3 END) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, size, reign
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

**If** your data is always in this simple form (meaning there are those three sizes only) and **if** you always want to select `large` first if present, else `medium` first if present and last `small`, this can just be done using `MIN` and `GROUP BY` with a good `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, MIN(size) AS size, reign
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, reign
ORDER BY id, size;
```

This query will produce exactly the result shown in your question.

Verify this here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jhw4VZyv)

If this logic is not sufficient to meet your requirements, please edit your question and explain more detailed what you need.

Comment: You're right: large < medium < small ... this is a good answer +1